# Loop through checkbox ID's to see if any are checked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a ballot for a election system and I need to loop through all the checkboxes on the ballot to see if they are checked or unchecked. You can only select (for example) 1 of the 5 boxes available. I am stuck and can not for the life of me figure this out. The following code is my function that runs when the user clicks the submit button.

This code works and submit my ballot but does not check the number of checkboxes checked.

```
For Each row As Object In candidatesTable.Rows
    If row(1) = ballot_ID Then
        Dim checkBox_ID = row(0)
        Dim CB As New CheckBox()
        CB = mainBallotDiv.FindControl(checkBox_ID)

        If CB.Checked Then
            Dim addVote As Integer = row("votes")
            addVote += 1
            candidatesAdapter.addVoteToCandidate(addVote, row(0))
            Dim section_ID As Integer = row(2)
            Dim voter As String = userGnumber
            Dim vote As Integer = checkBox_ID
            Dim hasVoted As Boolean = True
            votesAdapter.InsertVotes(ballot_ID, section_ID, voter, vote, hasVoted)
        End If
    End If
Next
Response.Redirect("~/voting/voted.aspx")
```

I have added a couple things to try and get this to run correctly but no luck, my code currently is the following.

```
Dim checkedCount As Integer
    For Each row As Object In candidatesTable.Rows
        If row(1) = ballot_ID Then
            Dim checkBox_ID = row(0)
            Dim CB As New CheckBox()
            CB = mainBallotDiv.FindControl(checkBox_ID)
            Dim section_idFromCB As Integer = candidatesAdapter.getsectionIDfromcandidateID(CB.ID)
            Dim voteLimit As Integer = sectionsAdapter.votesbysectionid(section_idFromCB)

            If CB.Checked Then
                checkedCount += 1
                Debug.Write(checkedCount)
                If checkedCount > voteLimit Then
                    ' error
                    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('You can not select that many check boxes.');</script>")
                    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)

                Else
                    ' pass

                    For Each Nrow As Object In candidatesTable.Rows
                        If Nrow(1) = ballot_ID Then
                            Dim NcheckBox_ID = row(0)
                            Dim NCB As New CheckBox()
                            NCB = mainBallotDiv.FindControl(NcheckBox_ID)
                            If NCB.Checked Then
                                Dim addVote As Integer = row("votes")
                                addVote += 1
                                candidatesAdapter.addVoteToCandidate(addVote, row(0))
                                Dim section_ID As Integer = row(2)
                                Dim voter As String = userGnumber
                                Dim vote As Integer = checkBox_ID
                                Dim hasVoted As Boolean = True
                                votesAdapter.InsertVotes(ballot_ID, section_ID, voter, vote, hasVoted)
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                    Response.Redirect("~/voting/voted.aspx")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Directcast might also come handy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my recommendation...

You can put them in a `List(Of CheckBox)` then you can access them anytime as needed as well as get any property you would need.

```
Dim lstChecked As New List(Of CheckBox)
lstChecked = divcontrol.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).Where(Function(ch) ch.Checked = True).ToList
```

`lstChecked` would be any `CheckBox` that would be checked...

Answer (score -2):

```
For Each checkBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
     ' do something
Next
```

Comment: I believe you are being down voted because, while code snippets are fine, answers aren't really worth much without some attempt at an explanation of what the code snippet is doing.

Comment: You're kidding me. What explanation is required for a convoluted single line of code in plain and simple english.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli without any explanation as to *why* you're recommending this particular solution, it's not clear to anyone whether or not this solution will work for them. Remember, you're not just answer for the OP, but you're also answering for everyone who finds your answer when looking for a solution a similar problem they might be having.