# Multiple if statements checking length of string and shortening

Tags: vb.net, performance, if-statement

I'm wondering if there's a better way of writing these multiple If statements?  I'm sure there is, I just can't figure out what it'd be.  In essence the code is just shortening the string.

```
                If text = "-----------------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "----------------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "---------------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "--------------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "-------------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "------------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "-----------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "----------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "---------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "--------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "-------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "------" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "-----" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "----" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "---" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
                If text = "--" Then
                    text = "-"
                End If
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could use regex; identifying an arbitrary number of repetitions of a single character is very straightforward as I recall.  If performance is a concern, I'd recommend profiling; as ugly as the code you've posted is, it's probably faster than any of the alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
If text.Length > 0 AndAlso text.All(Function(c) c = "-"c) Then text = "-"
```

Requested explanation (i found this actually pretty understandable):

Since a string implements `IEnumerable(Of Char)` you can use it like a collection of characters. The LINQ extension method `Enumerable.All` determines if all items in a sequence/collection match a given [predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710301/what-is-a-predicate-in-c)(returns `True`). In this case the predicate checks whether a given char is `"-"c`(the c at the end is necessary with `option strict on` to tell the compiler that this is a char and not a string). So only if all chars in the string are minuses this method returns `True`. As soon as `All` finds a different char it will return `False`.

If it returns `True` there are 1-n minuses and no other char, so the variable `text` can be `"-"`.

Comment: Downvoted because while code snippets are fine, answers aren't really worth much without some attempt at an explanation of what the code snippet is doing

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli: fixed

Answer (score 0):

what about?:

```
Dim maxLengthOfStringYouCompareTo As Integer = 17

Dim xxx As String = ""

Dim text As String = If((xxx.All(Function(charrr) charrr.ToString() = "-") OrElse xxx.Length <= maxLengthOfStringYouCompareTo), "-", "otherValue")
```

, but if do not need limitation, then remove

```
xxx.Length <= maxLengthOfStringYouCompareTo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
While text.Contains("--")
    text = text.Replace("--","-")
End While
```

Comment: I've been downvoted before with this comment: I believe you are being down voted because, while code snippets are fine, answers aren't really worth much without some attempt at an explanation of what the code snippet is doing. – Mike_OBrien Jun 13 at 16:11
And Mike's comment has been upvoted 4 times.
With the same rationale, the two answers above shall be downvoted too.

Comment: It's quite obvious what the code snippet is doing though... is it not?  Seems a bit pedantic.

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/dwPxSi8eTsKFEh0KSP01VQ.png
Judge yourself.

Comment: Downvoted because while code snippets are fine, answers aren't really worth much without some attempt at an explanation of what the code snippet is doing

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli: the reason why you got downvotes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44523866/284240) was not (only) that it was a code only answer. But because it didn't help OP to solve his issue(find checked checkboxes). it was just the first step. Another problem with your and the accepted answers approach: you don't find the checkboxes because they are nested in child controls.

Comment: Users like Alessandro Mandelli force me not to be more active here than now.